# compute weights by Generalized Hebbian Algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a task to do some calculations in matlab .. I use the Generalized Hebbian Algorithm to compute some weights , here is the functions of Hebbian Algorithm , slice 15
http://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/courses/eitn55/Downloads/ICA_Ch6.pdf

here is my code

```
alfa=0.5;
e=randn(3,5000);
A=[1 0 0;-0.5 0.5 0;0.3 0.1 0.1];
x=A*e;
W=rand(3);
nn=size(x);
for n=1:nn
    y=W*x(:,n);
    k=tril(y*y')*W;
    W(:,n+1)= alfa*(y*x(:,n)'-k);
end
```

In my task I know that x=A*e; 
but I do not know if I am iterating in correct way or not?
is my for loop doing correct?
and are those equations below correct?

```
    y=W*x(:,n);
    k=tril(y*y')*W;
    W(:,n+1)= alfa*(y*x(:,n)'-k);
```

`W(:,n+1)` should print out a 3*3 matrix (that what I understood)...
Matlab says when I run this code : Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check size of each matrix, you will find out that the order is incorrect:

```
size(x)
ans =
 3 5000

size(W)
ans = 
3 3
```

so you should multiply them as

```
for n=1:nn
    y=W*x;
end
```

However this part does not make sense either,

```
k=tril(y'*y)*W;
```

because `tril(y'*y)` is a matrix size `5000x5000` and `W` is `3x3`. So I guess you should change it to:

```
k=tril(y*y')*W;
```

Then `alfa*(y*x'-k);` would be a `3x3` matrix.

Comment: Can you please look at my edit and determine if I use correct matrix dimensions in `W(:,n+1)`  ..  do you think it is correct??? thanks

Comment: Why should you do `W(:,n+1)`? `W` is a `3x3` matrix and then `alfa*(y*x'-k)` creates another `3x3` matrix which are replaceable.